# Find a function $f(n)$ such that neither $f(n) = O(log n)$ nor $f(n) = \Omega(n)$ holds.

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Any hints on this problem?

I want to find a function $f(n)$ which is:

- NOT $f(n) = O(log n)$
- NOT $f(n) = \Omega(n)$

So it must hold that: $c_1 * log n < f(n) < c_2 * n$ and $c_1, c_2$ are some constants...

So I am looking for something which is smaller than $n$...can I say that $f(n) = 2 * n$?

Comment: An easy solution to $x$, when $a<x<b$, is $x=\frac{a+b}2$. I haven't worked with $O$ nor $\Omega$ though, so this comment might be useless

Comment: So I could choose $f(n) = \frac{c * (log(n) + n)}{2}$?

Comment: $f(n)=\tfrac 12(c_1\log(n)+c_2n)$ would be a solution to $c_1\log(n)<f(n)<c_2 n$, yes

Answer (score 1):

$h(n)=\sqrt{n}$ would be a good example.

Comment: I understand why $\sqrt n$ is always smaller than $n$ but I don't know how to proof that $c_1 * log n$ is always smaller than $\sqrt n$.

Comment: Its not always smaller...just eventually

Comment: You are wrong: it is not 'always smaller', check the definition of O(). To answer your quedtion though it is enough to take the limit of the ratio and see that it diverges.

Comment: $f(n) = \sqrt n = O(n) \Leftrightarrow \exists c \in \mathbb{R}, c > 0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}: \sqrt n < c * n$. This is true, e.g. $c = 10, n_0 = 1$.